# Float column width are not same like other column using tabulate

Tags: python, tabulate, sequence-alignment, python-tabulate

I have code where the `Selected Probability` value is float type, and im using `Tabulate` to print it into table.
The problem is the width of `Selected Probability` column. Here is the simplified code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

def calculate_fitness(total_watt):
    # Placeholder 
    return 42

def format_number(total_kwh):
    # Placeholder 
    return 42

def store_chromosome_attributes(chromosomes, table_data_p):
    chromosome_attributes = []

    headers = ["K", "Individual", "Fitness Value", "Selected Probability"]

    print(tabulate([], tablefmt="pipe", showindex=False, headers=headers))

    total_fitness_values = []
    cumulative_probability = 0

    for k_row in chromosomes:
        combined_row = [k_row[0]]
        individual_values = []

        for k_value, p_row in zip(k_row[1:11], table_data_p):
            if k_value == 1:
                combined_row.append(k_value)
                individual_values.append(str(k_value))
            else:
                combined_row.append(k_value)
                individual_values.append('0')

        selected_watt_values = [p_row[2] for k_value, p_row in zip(k_row[1:11], table_data_p) if k_value == 1]
        selected_kwh_values = [p_row[3] * 1352 for k_value, p_row in zip(k_row[1:11], table_data_p) if k_value == 1]

        total_watt = sum(selected_watt_values)
        total_kwh = sum(selected_kwh_values)
        fitness_value = calculate_fitness(total_watt)
        total_fitness_values.append(fitness_value)

        chromosome_attributes.append({
            'K': combined_row[0],
            'P_values': combined_row[1:11],
            'Total_Watt': total_watt,
            'Total_kWh': total_kwh,
            'Fitness_Value': fitness_value,
        })

    for attr in chromosome_attributes:
        attr['Selected_Probability'] = attr['Fitness_Value'] / sum(total_fitness_values) if sum(total_fitness_values) != 0 else 0.0
        cumulative_probability += attr['Selected_Probability']

    column_widths = [0, 11, 15, 30]  # Updated column widths
    rows_data = [
        [
            f"{attr['K']:<{column_widths[0]}}",
            f"{''.join(map(str, attr['P_values'])):>{column_widths[1]}}",
            f"{attr['Fitness_Value']:>{column_widths[2]}}",
            f"{attr['Selected_Probability']:.4f}",
        ] for attr in chromosome_attributes
    ]
    print(tabulate(rows_data, tablefmt="pipe", showindex=False))

    total_row_data = ["-" * 22, "Total", f"{sum(total_fitness_values):>{column_widths[2]}}", "0.0000"]
    print(tabulate([total_row_data], tablefmt="pipe", showindex=False))

    return chromosome_attributes

# Example usage:
chromosomes = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
table_data_p = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
            [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

store_chromosome_attributes(chromosomes, table_data_p)
```

When I run it, the width of the `Selected Probability` column is not dynamic or not the same as other Column width (Invidiual, Fitness Value):

```
| K   | Individual   | Fitness Value   | Selected Probability   |
|-----|--------------|-----------------|------------------------|
|--:|------------:|----------------:|----:|
| 1 |          01 |              42 | 0.5 |
| 0 |          10 |              42 | 0.5 |
|:-----------------------|:------|----------------:|--:|
| ---------------------- | Total |              84 | 0 |
```

The output should be:

```
| K   | Individual   | Fitness Value   | Selected Probability   |
|-----|--------------|-----------------|------------------------|
|----:|-------------:|----------------:|-----------------------:|
|  1  |           01 |              42 |                    0.5 |
|  0  |           10 |              42 |                    0.5 |
|:-------------------|:------|--------:|-----------------------:|
| ------------------ | Total |      84 |                      0 |
```

Comment: Please try to reduce the code to a [mre] and use English names so that we can understand more easily.

Comment: @wjandrea I already change to Z, the main problem is Z column width. If full code needed I will share on this comment

Comment: After the edit, the code is incomplete and it still has some details that don't seem relevant to the problem, like how `attr['Z']` is calculated. The point of a [mre] is that we can copy-paste the code and immediately reproduce the problem, as well as simplify the code so that the source of the problem becomes more obvious (which can actually help you spot it yourself).

Comment: I just noticed, for all columns except `Z`, you're setting the width with `column_widths[n]`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Uh so i already simplify the code so anyone can try it. Is it enough? The problem is the `Z` or `Selected Probability` column width its not same as others. So Im trying to manually set the width